# How to access to members value of a json document with mongoDB query? I am working with Java, I have a null pointer exception

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Sample Document

```
{
    "_id": "123",
    "type": "Article",
    "title": "abc",
    "pages": {
        "start": 67,
        "end": 88
    },
    "year": 2012,
    "booktitle": "def",
    "url": "unknown",
    "authors": [""]
}
```

//coll is a MongoCollection

//cursor is a FindIterable

//it is a MongoCursor

```
cursor = coll.find(gte("year", 2013)).projection(Projections.include("title"));
it = cursor.iterator();
Document tmp = new Document();
int nPages = 0;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    tmp = it.next();
    nPages = tmp.getInteger("pages.end") - tmp.getInteger("pages.start"); //null pointer exception here
    System.out.println(tmp);
    System.out.println("Number of pages: " + nPages);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to include pages attribute in projection. Numbers are stored as doubles in MongoDb.

```
double nPages = 0;
while (it.hasNext()) {
    tmp = it.next();
    nPages = ((Document)tmp.get("pages")).getDouble("end") - ((Document)tmp.get("pages")).getDouble("start");
    System.out.println(tmp);
    System.out.println("Number of pages: " + nPages);
 }
```